# What or who studies classification of thinking?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

**What branch of philosophy or what philosopher(s) study the classification of different types and processes of thinking (thought)?**

[Mortimer J. Adler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortimer_Adler) in his 1972 book ["How to read a book"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671212095) defines 3 types of so-called analytical reading:

1. Structural - when reader divides the text hierarchically until atomic parts (the propositions) are met;
2. Interpretive - when reader comprehends the propositions and arguments (set of premises that imply a conclusion)
3. Critical - when reader checks whether author is illogical, uninformed, misinformed or incomplete, and based on that agrees, disagrees or suspends judgement.

Now i thought that this quite reflects how the process of thinking works inside our brains: you structure, interpret and criticize the incoming information - and this is analytic (or systemic) thinking. However my classification is not rigorous and may not be true, so i'm interested, where can i find more systematic and formal articulation. But i don't know, which science deals with that kind of problem.

*Formal logic* isn't relevant, because it deals with specific mathematically rigorous reasoning process. *Semiotics* is a study of signs and while tangentially useful, does not deal with the process of thought either. *Linguistics* deals with language, and i'm interested in how semantics is extracted from the language, and how this action is formulated philosophically. *Cognitive sciences* deal with the exact material processes. So i thought my question should be in a field of philosophy of mind or epistemology.

Please advise on how to improve this question, if you find faults in it.

Comment: "Noology" might be one way to say this; certainly as you say it's effectively an epistemological problem.

Comment: How about "hermeneutics"?  It sounds to me like Gadamer's *Truth and Method* is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, the fields you listed are not all mutually exclusive, so I don't think you would come to a result by ruling something out.

Secondly, I think that your claim that "cognitive sciences deal with the exact material processes" is incorrect. Cognitive sciences are not (restricted to) neuroscience.

I would submit that [**cognitive psychology**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_psychology) is really the field of research you are looking for.